# Raspberry Pi 2 does not start SOMETIMES

Tags: raspbian

I started new with Raspberry Pi 2 a few weeks ago and I noticed something strange. Sometimes when I want to switch it ON, it does not switch ON, and instead both the red and yellow LEDs go ON, no blinking tho. But if I take out the power and eject the SD card and then insert the SD again and I try then it will turn ON.

What causes this? And how can I prevent this in case my raspberry pi is supposed to restart automatically repeatedly?

Comment: Which model Pi?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that. I will edit the question now.

Comment: It might be worth looking through http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting if you haven't already.

Comment: Maybe the SD card (holder) is slightly loose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who helped. This should give an extensive answer as taken from http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Pi_boots_sometimes_but_not_always

> With a known good power supply and known good SD card, the R-Pi boots
>   occasionally, but other times shows only a tiny green flicker from the
>   "OK" LED and it fails to start, even with no USB devices and no
>   Ethernet. This has been reported several times[6] [7] [8] and remains
>   an open issue. Low voltage or an improper SD card can cause it. Some
>   SD cards will work until they warm up slightly, and then fail[9]. When
>   exposed to 21 C room temperature the warmest part of an uncased
>   working R-Pi should be 41 C[10]. The wiki has a list of working SD
>   cards. Buy from a reliable vendor as it has been claimed that 1/3 of
>   all "Sandisk" labelled memory cards are counterfeit.
>
> - > It could be that the SD memory card is not making proper contact with
>   >     the Raspberry Pi. Look at the SD card holder on the Raspberry Pi
>   >     carefully. At first glance it may look fine, but the contacts must be
>   >     springy and they must protrude at least 2mm as measured from the lower
>   >     edge of the holder to the top of the contact bulge. Variations happen
>   >     due to the solder process and the type of holder used. Some of the
>   >     solder residue falls into the contact cavity, restricting the
>   >     springiness and the height that the contact protrudes. You can fix
>   >     this yourself, but remember you can void your warranty. The contacts
>   >     are delicate, so be careful. Insert a needle pin under the contact
>   >     bulge and pull lightly up until the one end of the contact unclips.
>   >     Clean the cavity where the contact unclipped from any solder or other
>   >     residue by blowing into the cavity. Clip the contact back into the
>   >     cavity by lightly pushing it into the cavity. Do this for all the
>   >     contacts. Refer to these photos: Media:SDcardHolder.JPG,
>   >     Media:UnclipContact.JPG, Media:UnclippedContact.JPG

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in my Raspberry Pi B+, the reason of no blinking LEDs is that there is power but the SD card isn't being read at that time. So Pi is nothing but a brainless powered card. You should make sure SD card hub is clean and dustless, it might cause corrupt connection which will end with the situation you have.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into strange issues where the RPi is not getting enough power.  I wouldn't power the RPi from a USB port on your laptop and make sure the wall plug supplies at least 2 amps.

Answer (score 1):

If you've got a display connected to your RPi, check to see if you have a little 4 color square in the top-right of the display when it does boot. If so, that's a sure indication you have inadequate power.

A lot of cheap power adapters have sufficient specs, but cheap cables or other factors result in inadequate power making it to the RPi. I recommend some of the heavier-duty adapters from Adafruit and other RPi sellers.